# How does GCC handle variable redefinition

Tags: c++, c, gcc, g++

I wrote a piece of code like this

```
int a;
int a = 100;
int main()
{
}
```

It was compiled successfully by **GCC**, but not by **G++**.

I guess GCC handle this by ignoring the first definition of variable a. But I want to know the precise rule so that I won't miss anything.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Please not: you should use `int main(void)`. You should also compile using `-Wall`

Comment: It's not a matter of gcc versus g++, it's a matter of C versus C++. Different languages, different rules.

Comment: @Eregrith I add -Wall, and gcc only remind me that there is no return in main function

Comment: @Mat Because I think this behavior for GCC is very strange, I thought it might be just an extension of GCC

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**In C**

```
int a;  /* Tentative definition */
int a = 100; /* Definition */
```

From **6.9.2 External object definitions** in C11 specs:

> A declaration of an identifier for an object that has file scope
>   **without an** initializer, and **without a** storage-class specifier or with
>   the storage-class specifier static, constitutes a **tentative
>   definition**. If a translation unit contains one or more tentative
>   definitions for an identifier, and the translation unit contains **no
>   external** definition for that identifier, then the behavior is exactly
>   as if the translation unit contains a file scope declaration of that
>   identifier, with the composite type as of the end of the translation
>   unit, with an initializer equal to 0.
>
> ```
> int i4; // tentative definition, external linkage
> static int i5; // tentative definition, internal linkage
> ```

---

**In C++**

`int a;` is a definition (not tentative) and because it is illegal to have multiple definitions of an object, it will not compile.

Comment: Thank you very much. The rule seems complex. Why does C have this a little confusing feature? Can you provide an example where we must use it?

Comment: I remember a discussion years back about what tentative definitions are good for and we concluded without any good use. So I am not aware of a good rationale.

Comment: GCC 10 changed the default to `-fno-common`, so tentative definitions should conflict with other definitions. [This link](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-10/porting_to.html) provides more details. I was facing a problem and this pointed me to the right direction, thanks!

Comment: Glad to see that this was helpful.